# Digital signature in browser without ActiveX/Java applet

Tags: javascript, browser, digital-signature

Is there any solutions / techniques to digitally sign file (of some other data) in browser without usage of ActiveX objects or Java applets?

Answer (score 4):

Something else is needed, such as Flash. While writing some digital signing code in pure JavaScript would not be a huge problem (though would require quite a lot of work and would work painfully slow), access to the certificate stored on local system is not possible with pure JavaScript. One of the options would probably be create an existing object (such as CAPICOM module), but (a) this is probably limited to IE and Windows, and (b) CAPICOM itself has been deprecated by Microsoft.

If your problem is that such objects need to be written, then our [Secureblackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/) product in version 9 (which is in public beta now) includes components and client modules (Java applet, ActiveX and Flash applet) to perform such distributed signing.

If you just want to avoid use of any external modules, then I am afraid you are out of luck. I also wish we could have something in pure JavaScript (this would simplify and improve our product as well), but the problem is with accessing the certificate on the client.

Answer (score 0):

[this project](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) should get your hopes up.  now the only thing left is to figure out how to get the certificate from the browser certificate store.  PKI is like a bollywood blockbuster -non-stop action, emotion, drama, comedy and at the end a complete waste of time and money, but we go to the next one because it is seems better than the last.